# Is it possible to catch SQL Server trigger or create own trigger for Server Data in C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, triggers

I found that it's possible to create server trigger from C# code.

But still can't find is it possible and how to subscribe to Server triggers or maybe design events based on sql server data change?

I think I can create an trigger on C# that will contact with my application with ... WCF? or somehow else, it should be not hard I think to create connection for C# -> C# there but is there examples, more native ways of catching sql server events from C# application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener with SqlDependency.Start(string),
 more information here: [SqlDependency MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)